# How to show message based on condition - using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, conditional-statements

Here is my controller code:

```
 public function getGroupAgainstMember(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $user =User::find($user_id);
    $groupDetails=$user->groups; // Trying to get property of non-object

    if (empty($groupDetails)) {
        $resultArray = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Group details.', 'data' => []];
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }
    if ($groupDetails)
        $resultArray = ['status' => true, 'message' => 'Group & Members details!', 'groups' => $groupDetails];
    else
        $resultArray = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Group details not found.', 'data' => []];
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

I am fetching records against user id and if user id exist it show me the data against this user id and if i enter random user id like 1233 it says  Trying to get property of non-object i have also mentioned this error on my code from where its coming.

I want to display a message that user id does not exist if i enter any id like 1234 i have also put condition if(empty($$groupDetails)) but not displaying the proper error message.

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you trying to get property of null. when user doesn't exist, `$user` is not an object and it has no any props

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
$groupDetails = ($user) ? $user->groups : collect([]); // if user exists get groups, if not - empty collection
```

> I want to display a message that user id does not exist

then you can just do that way:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
if (null === $user) { // or just if (!$user)
    $resultArray = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'User does not exist.', 'data' => []];
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
$user =User::find($user_id);
```

you can add something like this:

```
if(!$user){
    return response()->json(["message"=>"User not found"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a message that user id does not exist

```
 public function getGroupAgainstMember(Request $request){

    $post = $request->all();

    $user = User::find($post['user_id']);

    if($user){
         // your code
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => 'User not found']);
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two issues in your code which are as below:-
First, check if the relationship with groups exist or not using dd().If you get the data correctly then check whether groupdetails is empty or not.

Second, the problem is that you are using empty function to check if groupdetails is empty or not. After that again you are using if condition to check whether groupdetails exist or not. It is one and the same. No need to use two if conditions for checking whether group details is empty or not. You just need to do

```
 if (empty($groupDetails)) {
        $resultArray = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Group details.', 'data' => []];
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }
else{
     $resultArray = ['status' => true, 'message' => 'Group & Members details!', 'groups' => $groupDetails]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation

```
$request->validate([
'user_id' => 'exists:App\Models\User,id'
]);
```

This will automatically give a not found message

here you can find some more information: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation